# React-Redux load firebase auth current user in the redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I try to persist the **redux store** state with the **currentUser** from the **Firebase Auth**. When I try to access auth.currentUser I get null and I think it's because the **currentUser** info is loaded asynchronously. What I want is to make my application wait until I fetch the **currentUser** and then to load the **currentUser** inside the redux store to access it in my application.

**Store.js**

```
import { auth } from "../firebase"
const preloadedState = {
    account: auth.currentUser
}
export const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    preloadedState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)),
)
```

**Firebase.js**

```
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
```

How should I wait for currentUser to be fetched and then load inside the redux store to keep the user authenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data), you're supposed to use an auth state observer to get a callback when the user state changes.  You can use this information to update your store.  (Don't think about this as "waiting" for information - you are respond to changes in state when they happen.)

> Attach the observer using the onAuthStateChanged method. When a user
> successfully signs in, you can get information about the user in the
> observer.
>
> ```
> import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
>
> const auth = getAuth();
> onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
>   if (user) {
>     // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
>     // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
>     const uid = user.uid;
>     // ...
>   } else {
>     // User is signed out
>     // ...
>   }
> });
> ```